# convert string value in ate format in java script

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-design-studio

i have a problem in converting a string date value into valid date format in pentaho-data-itegration .could someone help me to convert string date'08-Mar-2017' into date format  (2017-03-08 00:00:00) in pentaho.

Answer (score 1):

**Date do not have a format in PDI**.

To convert the '08-Mar-2017' string to a date, use the `Select value` step, `Meta-data` tab, and tell your field should be of type `Date`, and the conversion format is `dd-MMM-yyyy` (type it, as it not on the drop down list).

To convert the date to the '2017-03-08 00:00:00' string, use the `Select value` step, `Meta-data` tab, and tell your field should be of type `String`, and the conversion format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

**However, you most probably do not need to do it.**

The only time a date format is used is for data input and output. Plus it is transparent, most of the time.

If your data comes from a file or data grid or a computation or many other steps, you can specify its format. If is comes from a `Input table`, think about converting with the sql build-in function : to-date, convert, cast, date depending on your database system.

If your output is a file or an Excel or a script, you can specify its format (which by default is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`). If it's a sql insert or update, don't do anything and let the databases do the conversion.

Comment: thanks for your response ..i solved it through  spoon builtin function date2str  and also used str2dat for conversion .it gave me the format which i needed for .

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to convert between date and string, and the build-in javascript function is a way to do this in one step. Can you publish your solution or accept mine, to help the community.

Comment: Kindly find the statement i used for the solution of string conversion  ........var sql1 =str2date(SPUD_DATE,"dd-MMM-yy"); 
sql1= date2str(sql1,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");